# Setting up a VNC server in Linux

Tags: centos, vnc

I have a CentOS box for which I would like to set up a VNC server. (This is not a production server, just my home computer.)

I'm used to the RealVNC server in Windows, which just shows you the same screen that the local user sees. I tried a few VNC servers that came with my distro, but the only one I got to work showed me a very ugly non-Gnome desktop.

Is there a normal VNC server for CentOS which shows the client the same desktop that the local users sees?

Answer (score 1):

Just use regular VNC server, and on the file:

```
~/.vnc/xstartup
```

Put the instruction:

```
gnome-session
```

And you are done. You'll get a beautiful gnome desktop on your VNC session instead of what you are currently getting, since the default option is just to display a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer but -

Another alternative to VNC that you may want to consider (particularly if you are logging in over a low-bandwidth connection or if you appreciate having the connection protected by high-grade security) is [NX](http://www.nomachine.com/). I have generally found it better than either VNC of XDMCP in terms of setup and more responsive in use.

Answer (score 0):

try veno server, it is a wrapper for vnc that shows/shares the desktop similar to RealVNC, its the RDP server for the ubuntu's